# Securely displaying images with Amazon S3 in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I'd like to securely display a grid of thumbnail images to an authenticated user on our site. All the images will be stored in Amazon S3.

One way, I suppose, is to implement "security by obscurity" by uploading these images with public read access, and making the keys long and random.

I also could set up ACLs, but then I'd have to disclose the access key in the url (I think), or pull the image into my application via the API and display it securely through the web server.

Is there a preferred way to do this? And to be able to display the images quickly without requiring tremendous requests to S3 from the server every time a page is generated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate urls to s3 with an expiry date. Generating such a URL does not require a request to S3 and does not result in the disclosure of your secret key: you use your secret key to generate a signature that is appended to the URL (the access key id is in that URL but that's ok)

See [the docs on query string authorization](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)